# How to change the color of options inside <select> menu?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

the problem is real! No idea how to do it... Is this even possible?
I want have white letters in this menu:

[image]

My code:

```
<select id="addRow-fieldType" style="margin-top: 10px; width: 180px; ">
    <option value="null">NUMBER</option>
    <option value="2">CHAR(32)</option>
    <option value="3">DATE</option>
    <option value="4">VARCHAR</option>
    <option value="5">BLOB</option>
</select>
```

Comment: add inline style attribute style="color:#fff" to any of the options you want or add option{color: #fff} to your stylesheet.

Comment: I tried... This method dont work for me too.
Look there are my styles in chrome:
https://i.ibb.co/xqwhRFp/image.png
And chrome ignore this color "white" i dont know why

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this:

```css
select option {
  margin: 40px;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  color: #fff;
  text-shadow: 0 1px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
}

select option[value="1"] {
  background: rgba(100, 100, 100, 0.3);
}

select option[value="2"] {
  background: rgba(150, 150, 150, 0.3);
}

select option[value="3"] {
  background: rgba(200, 200, 200, 0.3);
}

select option[value="4"] {
  background: rgba(250, 250, 250, 0.3);
}
```

```html
<select id="addRow-fieldType" style="margin-top: 10px; width: 180px; ">
    <option value="null">NUMBER</option>
    <option value="2">CHAR(32)</option>
    <option value="3">DATE</option>
    <option value="4">VARCHAR</option>
    <option value="5">BLOB</option>
</select>
```

Comment: This is strange... This method don't work in my code... Look here is screen from f12 chrome: 
https://i.ibb.co/xqwhRFp/image.png

Anyone have idea what is going on?

Comment: okay i fixed that. Problem was on the jquery side.
I change color of "ui-widget-content" in jquery-ui-min.css  and that was a solution